# Creating a table conditionally in SQlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is probably very basic stuff. I want to create a table if a certain condition is met. Basically I have a db with a version number, and if the version is as expected, a new table is created.

This is pretty straightforward to do, say, in python, but is there a pure SQL way, or then a pure SQLite way, of doing this? Basically I want to know if my update scripts could be free of any other programming langage other than SQL (or SQLite's SQL).

I looked at the CASE clause but it seems I can't use it as a top-level switch statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this.  SQLite has no flow control statements and the only `if` condition you can specify on the `CREATE TABLE` command is `IF NOT EXISTS`.

You will have to use a scripting language to execute this logic.